# Deleting a few particles (flowers in a field)

Tags: particles

I want to delete a few flowers from a certain area on a flower field. Besides the flower particles there is also grass and when I attempt to select only the flowers and go into edit mode to delete them, both the particle systems aren't seen in edit mode. Does anyone know a way to delete the flowers but only from a certain area?

Comment: you can use a vertex group to determine where a particle system is generated, have you used this option?

Comment: Just to clarify, you go into edit mode to modify the base mesh.  The particle system you're using distributes instances of that mesh over the emitter object.  If you make a change to the base mesh it will be reflected on all instances.  "Particle edit mode" is also available but I'm not sure it works with particles set to render as objects.

Comment: Is it using the filter option in vertex groups? I don't think I attempted that but am not too sure how to approach it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create 2 particle systems, one for the grass, one for the flowers, under *Emission*, change the *Seed* value if they overlap:

[image]

To make the grass appear on some parts only, create a vertex group in *Weight Paint* mode:

[image]

In the *Particle System* panel, under *Vertex Groups > Density* (and maybe *Length*) select the vertex group, the particle will only appear where you've painted your vertex group:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! I will attempt this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you it worked!